# htaccess show internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, seo

i have facing some problem in htaccess i can't understand what the issue is that .. i would like to make SEO friendly URLs but when i write **RewriteEngine on** given error show on website

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

my website folder are.
- includes
- logs
- public

and .htaccess file available on main.
and index.php available in public folder .
and htaccess file i was put in public folder same error show.
In Include folder all class has been defined.
In public folder all publicily available pages

htaccess File Code is :

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Comment: Can you show us your htaccess ?

Comment: htaccess code is simple RewriteEngine on

Comment: Have you enable `mod_rewrite` with `a2enmod` ?

Comment: how can i enable `mod_rewrite`  Adrien Lacroix

Comment: Have you an direct access to shell with your server ?
A simply method to check if it's here is to use the php method `phpinfo();` on a page and check if it's here

Comment: Thanks PRoblem Solved When I enable `mod_rewrite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server doesn't have the rewrite module loaded.  You'll need to make sure this is installed and that your server is configured to load it.  How you do this depends on which operating system you use.

If you are using a hosting provider rather than your own server, it is likely you don't have the access necessary to do this, in this case, contact support and ask them about it.